# Knit HTML fails to output upon code error

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, boxplot

My R script creates a series of matrices and boxplots of those matrixes. It is possible that one of the matrices may be empty. Executing `boxplot` of an empty matrix gives an error. That is not a problem. The problem is, when running this code in R Markdown to knit an HTML file, this error halts the execution and results in no HTML file.

As a patch, I though to run `boxplot` only if the matrix is not all NAs. That works. Yet I'd like to know if I could get knitr to simply ignore this error, rather than patch my code. Thank you.

This is the error message:

```
Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
Calls: <Anonymous> ... boxplot -> boxplot.default -> do.call -> bxp -> plot.window
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Execution halted
```

Reproducible code:

````
```{r,echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)

#MatrixPos - not empty
MatrixPos <- structure(list(difFwd1 = 0, difFwd2 = 0.200000000000045, difFwd3 = 0.100000000000136,difFwd4 = 0, difFwd5 = 0.200000000000045), .Names = c("difFwd1","difFwd2", "difFwd3", "difFwd4", "difFwd5"), row.names = "155", class = "data.frame") 

#MatrixNeg - empty
MatrixNeg <- structure(list(difFwd1 = NA_real_, difFwd2 = NA_real_, difFwd3 = NA_real_,difFwd4 = NA_real_, difFwd5 = NA_real_), .Names = c("difFwd1","difFwd2", "difFwd3", "difFwd4", "difFwd5"), row.names = "NA", class = "data.frame") 

boxplot(MatrixPos, notch = TRUE, outline = TRUE)
boxplot(MatrixNeg, notch = TRUE, outline = TRUE)

```
###note must remove the four spaces for the code to work in R-Studio


#Solution attempt:
if(!all(is.na(MatrixNeg))) boxplot(MatrixNeg, notch = TRUE, outline = TRUE)
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `error=TRUE` in your chunk options

````
```{r,echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message=FALSE, error=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)

#MatrixPos - not empty
MatrixPos <- structure(list(difFwd1 = 0, difFwd2 = 0.200000000000045, difFwd3 = 0.100000000000136,difFwd4 = 0, difFwd5 = 0.200000000000045), .Names = c("difFwd1","difFwd2", "difFwd3", "difFwd4", "difFwd5"), row.names = "155", class = "data.frame") 

#MatrixNeg - empty
MatrixNeg <- structure(list(difFwd1 = NA_real_, difFwd2 = NA_real_, difFwd3 = NA_real_,difFwd4 = NA_real_, difFwd5 = NA_real_), .Names = c("difFwd1","difFwd2", "difFwd3", "difFwd4", "difFwd5"), row.names = "NA", class = "data.frame") 

boxplot(MatrixPos, notch = TRUE, outline = TRUE)
boxplot(MatrixNeg, notch = TRUE, outline = TRUE)

```
````

gives this result:
[image]

From the [knitr options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/): "error: (TRUE; logical) whether to preserve errors (from stop()); by default, the evaluation will not stop even in case of errors!! if we want R to stop on errors, we need to set this option to FALSE"

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple answer. Just couldn't find it. Thanks vm.

Comment: I think you can add `cache` to chunk options too: `{r, cache = TRUE, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, error = TRUE}`

Comment: @Pgibas thats true, I just wasn't sure if there was some other reason he left it out (haven't seen the rest of his code)